# Catch to avoid System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, forms, exception, picturebox

When I size up a pictureBox to be really big, I get a "**System.AccessViolationException**" exception. But I can't seem to avoid it with a try / catch... How can I get this to not throw an exception?

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pic.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\barren.jpg");
            pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                pic.Width = 30000;
                pic.Height = 35000;
            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show("catch"); }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the code doing the resizing is failing in unmanaged code. There's not a lot you can do about this.

Comment: Hmmm, don't really understand that much. So there's really no way to not make it crash?

Comment: You're trying to make the `PictureBox` a ridiculously large size, which is causing the native code (GDI+) underlying it to fail, hence the `AccessViolationException`. About the only thing you can do is avoid specifying such huge values - you can catch an `AccessViolationException`, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help everybody.